# Keycloak - Spring Security - CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

i'm using keycloak (v. 10) for make authentication for existing spring (no boot library) application. I'am using the java-adapter from [keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#java-adapters) i added the suggested configuration on my spring security config.

This is my keycloak.json file:

```
{
  "realm": "cnp-server",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8081/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "cnpserver-client",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

On this screen the configuration of keycloak client (is running on docker):
[image: configuration of cnpserver-client]

When i try to access to application, the browser make a redirection to:

```
http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/cnp-server/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=cnpserver-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8088%2Fcnp_server_web_war%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=73ee7ebe-1949-4e94-9349-f3760f37bb4a&login=true&scope=openid
```

When i key the access credentials on prompt box, somethings going wrong; on Keycloak log:

WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-63) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=cnp-server, clientId=cnpserver-client, userId=null, ipAddress=192.168.32.1, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=7972a766-f9be-4907-85a7-69e6d5d50cbf, client_auth_method=client-secret

On spring application log:

ERROR  org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator [OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:337] - failed to turn code into token
ERROR org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator [OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:338] - status from server: 400
ERROR org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator [OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:340] -    {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code not valid"}

It's seems  similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860313/keycloak-code-to-token-error-after-user-is-authenticated) topic, but i don't make any personal configuration on redirect-uri (and i don't know how i can change that).
Thanks